# If set A is complete, prove that A is closed(proof-explanation)

Tags: proof-explanation, cauchy-sequences

[image]

I marked a place, which confuses me:

So, how do we know, that if A is complete it means, that sequence ${x_n}$ converges to a point, that belongs to A?

Comment: Isn't that just the definition of complete? Note that $x_n$ is a Cauchy-sequence, not any sequence.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just have written the definiton of comlete incorrectly.
Sorry.

Comment: It is just the definition of complete subset.